# Не работает модуль pyttsx3: "ImportError: No module named Foundation"

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

Почему так :

```
>>> import pyttsx3
>>> engine = pyttsx3.init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Foundation import *
ImportError: No module named Foundation
```

Comment: Там [на сайте](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/) есть дополнительная инструкция: если появляются ошибки типа `No module named win32com.client`, `No module named win32`, `No module named win32api`, установите также `pypiwin32`. Посмотрите ещё [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614648/importerror-no-module-named-foundation)

Comment: Я уже писал pip install pyobjc 
но по  прежнему ошибка.:>>> import pyobjc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyobjc
Соответственно:
ImportError: No module named Foundation